# Doubt about a limit using sandwich theorem

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits

I was seeing the following limit on an internet page: $$\lim_{x\to 0} x^2 \sin \frac{\pi}{x^2}$$ and in the explanation of the solution given by the page it says that for $x$ between $-1$ and $1$, $\sin(\frac{\pi}{x^2})$ verified that it's bounded between $-1$ and $1$. I don't understand why the resolution limits $x$ to those values ​​because I interpret that the sin will be limited between $-1$ and $1$ for all $x \not = 0$

I post below an screen capture of the explanation I'm talking about.

[image]

Comment: In general $-1 \leq \sin \theta \leq 1$ so it is bounded no matter what $\theta$ is.

Comment: Yes, the sine function is bounded for all values of ##x##. That was the bounded part of the hint. Now what does that mean for the product?

Comment: Yes, the sine function is globally bounded. However, for the limit it is enough to look only at a deleted neighborhood of $0$. So the fact that it is bounded when  $x\in [-1,1]\setminus\{0\}$ is enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We know that for any angle $\theta$, $$-1\le\sin\theta\le1$$
This means we also have $$-1\le\sin\left(\dfrac\pi{x^2}\right)\le1$$
When $$\begin{equation}\begin{split}\sin\left(\dfrac\pi{x^2}\right)&=1\\\dfrac\pi{x^2}&=\dfrac\pi2\\x^2&=2\\x&=\pm\sqrt 2\end{split}\qquad\begin{split}\sin\left(\dfrac\pi{x^2}\right)&=-1\\\dfrac\pi{x^2}&=-\dfrac\pi2\\x^2&=-2\implies x\in \mathbb{C}\end{split}\end{equation}$$

So the inequality is valid for $x\in\left(-\sqrt2,0)\cup(0,\sqrt2\right)$.

This means, since we are considering the limit around $x=0$, it suffices to narrow down the search area to a domain where $$x\in(-1,0)\cup(0,1)$$

Comment: I really don't get the point of calculating these values of $x$ when $\sin(\pi/x^2)=\pm 1$. Does that really matter as far evaluation of the limit in question in concerned?